# Retrieving Null from DB

Tags: sql, c, db2

I had written a code:

```
EXEC SQL
SELECT COLUMN.NAME into :h_HOST_VARIABLE :i_HOST_VARIABLE
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE
someCondition......
```

The column from which data is being fetched is *NULL*-able. There was already some value in **h_HOST_VARIABLE**, so when this query was executed the value in that column was **NULL**.

So I was expecting that the host variable would be set to **NULL** (due to which I didn't memset the host variable) but it didn't happen, it retained it's previous value. Why did this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as designed.
[Identifying null SQL values with null indicator variables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.embed.doc/doc/t0005636.html):

> The null-indicator variable is examined for a negative value. If the
>   value is not negative, the application can use the returned value of
>   the host variable. **If the value is negative, the fetched value is
>   null and the host variable should not be used. The database manager
>   does not change the value of the host variable in this case**.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
EXEC SQL
SELECT nvl(COLUMN.NAME,null) into :h_HOST_VARIABLE :i_HOST_VARIABLE
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE
someCondition......
```

Comment: If you actually try this in DB2 you'll get a syntax error

Comment: This question is tagged for DB2 not Oracle.  If you attempt to use NULL inside an NVL expression in DB2 you get a syntax error.  Your example doesn't work in DB2.